# technology tag [postgres] instead of [postgresql] in Careers

Tags: support, tags, jobs, retag-request

In SO the tag for PostgreSQL is correct [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), but on Careers technology tag `postgresql` doesn't exist (or at least not in auto-complete dropdown), but rather one with pre-2004 name of that database: `postgres`. I believe these tags should be in sync.

EDIT: I'm referring to technologies, which you can put in your profile.

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/postgresql  `[postgresql]` certainly *seems* to exist, do you mean for the experience and like/dislike section on your careers profile?

Comment: @Daniel: take a closer look at the results on the link you've provided, only one is actually tagged "postgresql", rest of them are tagged "postgres"

Comment: ok, thanks for the question update